# Using simple copy and paste to get the song list out of the new itunes 11

Tags: itunes

Before iTunes 11, I was able to simply select my view options for the playlist, highlight my songs, hit copy, and paste them into a blog post.

Now, with iTunes 11, it seems I am unable to do something so simple. I found a workaround for now, printing the playlist as a pdf and copying the contents into a blog post. This is irritating to me, as I need something much quicker and more efficient.

Does anyone know how to get back the simple copy and paste functionality? Or is there a simple way similar to this? I don't want to export to an excel file or export the whole library, I just want the view options I have selected, artist, track, and album, not the entirety of each song's information.

Comment: That is what we are trying to achieve. It doesn't work for me, either. I get embedded media -- a speaker icon in Pages, a playback widget in Text Edit. Have tried with both the menu and cmd-C. I am on Lion. Perhaps it is an OS-level difference?

Comment: @Jim Did you try pasting to a plain text view (or selecting Make Plain Text in TextEdit)?

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, don't have this problem.
Is the *Edit/Copy* entry enabled for you?
Because if I hit copy, and then paste into a text file, for given screenshot I obtain :

> 2 of 12   Aquele plano para me esquecer       Adriana Calcanhotto     O micróbio do samba Brasileira  6   60  3:01
>   6 Suavemente      Elvis Crespo    5* /
>   Top40     Latin   2   100 4:24
>   12    La Camisa Negra     Juanes  5*/Top40        Pop     100 3:35
>   1 I Need A Dollar     Aloe Blacc  5* /
>   Top40     Soul    4   100 4:04

[image]

is it what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: If you are using wordpress for your blog, like I am, I used the little icon of a clipboard with a T in it, which stands for insert plain text.  They also have a W one next to it which is for insert from Microsoft Word.  The plain text (T) one worked for me, hopefully it will work for you.  Maybe you could try pasting into Text Edit and then copying from there if you don't use Wordpress for your blog

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity's sake, ensure you're in a plain list view, either Songs or Playlist as @kraymer also shows. You cannot accomplish this from the large cover art views.

More specifically I suggest you create a playlist that has your view options enabled, add songs to it, and clear it when you're done.

It is still possible to copy/paste these entries as you were able to do previously:

```
Rocket Man  3:27    Aethernaut  6 of 11 Steam Fist Island II
Obstacle Course 4:00    Aethernaut  8 of 11 Steam Fist Island II
Unpause the Heat    3:19    Aethernaut  1 of 5  Super Mega Ultra
The Moon    3:23    Aethernaut  1 of 1  The Moon
2011-2010=1 2:19    Aethernaut  1 of 6  2011-2003=8
2011-2009=2 3:41    Aethernaut  2 of 6  2011-2003=8
2011-2008=3 3:15    Aethernaut  3 of 6  2011-2003=8
2011-2007=4 3:28    Aethernaut  4 of 6  2011-2003=8
2011-2006=5 4:17    Aethernaut  5 of 6  2011-2003=8
2011-2005=6 4:04    Aethernaut  6 of 6  2011-2003=8
```

[image: iTunes Playlist Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Ok I just ran into this same problem. I do a radio show and used tone able to copy an iTunes playlist, then go into Excel and paste it into a pre formatted template spreadsheet to print out. That no longer works. The hits were in the comments above. Below are the steps I had to do:

1. Select and copy the playlist in iTunes.
2. Open an new document in Textedit and Choose "Make Plain Text" from the "Format" menu. 3. Paste into the new plain text textedit document(this makes the text you want instead of pasting the songs.
3. Now while you are still in the plain text textedit document select all and copy.
4. Go into to document where you want to paste the data, (in my case I do it in an Excel document)
5. Now just paste the data in

What I am doing is using a plain text document to make the data I copied from iTunes i to plain text then I and copying that plain text version and pasting it where I want it to be.

Answer (score 1):

### So here is the script:

```
(*
"Export As HTML Table" for iTunes
written by Doug Adams
dougadams@mac.com

v1.5 mar 15 '04
-- includes composer, rating, and grouping options
(this script had not been updated since December of 2001!)

Get more free AppleScripts and info on writing your own
at Doug's AppleScripts for iTunes
http://www.malcolmadams.com/itunes/
*)
-------------------------------------------------------
-------------------------------------------------------
-- U S E R - C U S T O M I Z A B L E    O P T I O N S 
-- maintain quotes!
-- M A K E   C H A N G E S   A N D   S A V E  (command-s)
-------------------------------------------------------
-- initial HTML options
property myBackgroundColor : "white" -- background color, can also use "#ffffff", etc
property myTextColor : "black" -- text color, can also use "#000000", etc

-- table attributes
property mycellpadding : "1" -- padding inside cells
property mycellspacing : "0" -- padding outside between cells
property myborder : "1" -- thickness of table border, 0 is no border

-- Title line attributes
property myTitleJustification : "center" -- (left, center, or right) justification in main title cell 

-- TH attributes
property myTHJustification : "left" -- (left, center, or right) justification in column headers

-- TD attributes
property myTDJustification : "left" -- (left, center, or right) justification in data cells

-- face & size 
-- size can be relative (-1,-2,+1,+2, etcetera) or 1,2,3,4,5 -- smaller IS better!
-- font can be set to any installed font

-- top line where name of playlist, number of songs, time, and length appear
property myTitleFont : "Geneva" -- font for title line
property myTitlesize : "-2" -- font size for title line

-- column headers
property myTHFont : "Geneva" -- font for headers
property myTHsize : "-2" -- font size for headers

-- text in cells
property myTDFont : "Geneva" -- font for data
property myTDsize : "-2" -- font size for data
-------------------------------------------------------
-------------------------------------------------------
-- DON'T CHANGE ANYTHING BELOW UNLESS
-- YOU KNOW WHAT YOU'RE DOING ;)
-------------------------------------------------------
property myChoices : {"Artist", "Album"} -- remember last batch or always default to these
property myOptions : {"Play Order", "Artist", "Album", "Composer", "Genre", "Grouping", "Rating", "Size", "Time", "Track Number", ¬
    "Track Count", "Year", "Date", "Date Added", "Bit rate", "Sample rate", ¬
    "Volume", "Kind", "EQ", "Comment", "Location"}
global html_contents, thePlaylist, file_name, TDopen, TDclose, THopen, THclose, do_number

property okflag : false
-------------------------------------------------------
-- OKAY, LET'S GO!
-- check if iTunes is running 
tell application "System Events"
    if (get name of every process) contains "iTunes" then set okflag to true
end tell
if okflag then -- iTunes is running, let's go
    tell application "iTunes"
        -- ask user
        set myNewChoices to (choose from list myOptions with prompt ¬
            "Include table cells for which selected items below?" & return & "(\"Title\" is always included.)" default items myChoices OK button name ¬
            "Choose" cancel button name "Cancel" with multiple selections allowed and empty selection allowed)
        if myNewChoices is false then error number -128 -- cancel was clicked

        copy myNewChoices to myChoices
        --initial iTunes variables
        set thePlaylist to the front window's view
        my get_the_file_name()

        -- which tracks to use?
        if selection is {} then
            set allTracks to every track of thePlaylist
            set tableTitle to "Playlist: "
        else
            set allTracks to a reference to selection
            set tableTitle to "Selected in Playlist: "
        end if

        -- fig total tracks time, size, and number even if selection
        set totalSeconds to 0
        set totalSize to 0
        repeat with this_track in allTracks
            set totalSeconds to totalSeconds + (this_track's duration)
            set totalSize to totalSize + (this_track's size)
        end repeat
        set myTotalTrackTime to (my calc_total_time(totalSeconds))
        set myTotalTrackSize to (my calc_size(totalSize))

        set num_of_tracks to (count of allTracks)
        set s to "s"
        if num_of_tracks is 1 then set s to ""

        -- initialize some elements
        -- open and close for all TD & TH cells
        set TDopen to "<td align=" & myTDJustification & "><p><font face=" & myTDFont & " size=" & myTDsize & ">"
        set TDclose to "</font></p></td>"
        set THopen to "<th align=" & myTHJustification & "><font face=" & myTHFont & " size=" & myTHsize & ">"
        set THclose to "</font></th>"
        -- removed <p> tags from <TH> 'cause Netscape doesn't like correct HTML spec

        -- how many columns in table
        set myColspan to ((count of myChoices) + 1) -- number of cells across = number of all myChoices plus Title always chosen
        --  end then begin new table row
        set startNewRow to "</tr>" & return & "<tr>"
        --begin page
        set startHTML to ((("<html>" & ¬
            "<head><title>" & tableTitle & (get thePlaylist's name) & "</title></head>" & return ¬
            & "<body bgcolor=" & myBackgroundColor & " text=" & myTextColor & ">" & return & ¬
            "<table cellpadding=" & mycellpadding ¬
            & " cellspacing=" & mycellspacing ¬
            & " border=" & myborder ¬
            & " width=100%>" & return & "<tr>" & return & "<td colspan=" & myColspan as string) ¬
            & " align=" & myTitleJustification & "><p><font face=" & myTitleFont & " size=" & myTitlesize & ">" & tableTitle & "<b>" & thePlaylist's name ¬
            & "</b> " & num_of_tracks as string) & " song" & s & ", " & myTotalTrackTime ¬
            & " total time, " & myTotalTrackSize) & TDclose & return & "</tr>" & return & ¬
            "<tr>" & return & (my make_headers()) as string
        -- end page
        set endHTML to "</tr>" & return & "</table>" & return & "</body></html>"

        -- init main container
        set html_contents to ""
        -------------------------------------------------------
        -- S T A R T   T H E   P A G E  
        -------------------------------------------------------

        my add_to_contents(startHTML)

        repeat with thisTrack in allTracks -- do each track for each row

            my add_to_contents(startNewRow)

            if do_number is 2 then my add_another_TD(thisTrack's index as string)

            my add_another_TD(thisTrack's name) -- must always appear!

            if myChoices contains "Artist" then my add_another_TD(thisTrack's artist)

            if myChoices contains "Album" then my add_another_TD(thisTrack's album)

            if myChoices contains "Composer" then my add_another_TD(thisTrack's composer)

            if myChoices contains "Genre" then my add_another_TD(thisTrack's genre)

            if myChoices contains "Grouping" then my add_another_TD(thisTrack's grouping)

            if myChoices contains "Rating" then my add_another_TD(thisTrack's rating)

            if myChoices contains "Size" then -- size calculation
                my add_another_TD(my calc_size(thisTrack's size))
            end if

            if myChoices contains "Time" then my add_another_TD(thisTrack's time as string)

            if myChoices contains "Track Number" then my add_another_TD(thisTrack's track number as string)

            if myChoices contains "Track Count" then my add_another_TD(thisTrack's track count as string)

            if myChoices contains "Year" then my add_another_TD(thisTrack's year as string)

            if myChoices contains "Date" then
                my add_another_TD(my fix_date_string(thisTrack's modification date))
            end if

            if myChoices contains "Date Added" then
                my add_another_TD(my fix_date_string(thisTrack's date added))
            end if

            if myChoices contains "Bit rate" then my add_another_TD(thisTrack's bit rate as string)

            if myChoices contains "Sample rate" then my add_another_TD(thisTrack's sample rate as string)

            if myChoices contains "Volume" then my add_another_TD(thisTrack's volume adjustment as string)

            if myChoices contains "Kind" then my add_another_TD(thisTrack's kind)

            if myChoices contains "EQ" then my add_another_TD(thisTrack's EQ)

            if myChoices contains "Comment" then my add_another_TD(thisTrack's comment)

            if myChoices contains "Location" then
                set myLocation to (thisTrack's location as text)
                if myLocation is "missing value" then
                    set myLocation to "<i>not available on local drive</i>"
                end if
                my add_another_TD(myLocation)
            end if

        end repeat

        my add_to_contents(endHTML)
        -- contents now assembled
    end tell -- iTunes

    -------------------------------------------------------
    -- S A V E   F I L E  &  E N D
    -------------------------------------------------------

    my Make_The_File(file_name, html_contents as string)
    set dMes to return & return & "Would you like to view the exported HTML file?"
    set myEnding to (display dialog "Done!" & dMes buttons {"Done", "Yes"} default button 2 with icon 1 giving up after 30)
    if button returned of myEnding is "Yes" or gave up of myEnding is true then
        tell application "TextEdit"
            activate
            try
                open (file_name as alias)
            on error errMs
                display dialog errMs buttons {"Cancel"}
            end try
        end tell
    end if -- button is "Done"
end if -- iTunes not running

-------------------------------------------------------
-- S U B R O U T I N E S ----------------------------
-------------------------------------------------------
-- create file in Finder
to Make_The_File(file_name, cont)
    try
        copy (open for access file_name with write permission) to fileRef
        write cont to fileRef
        --set eof of fileRef to (length of cont)
        close access fileRef
    on error m number n
        try
            close access fileRefr
        end try
        if (n is equal to -48) then
            --display dialog "File exists"
            do shell script "rm " & quoted form of POSIX path of file_name
            my Make_The_File(file_name, cont)
        else
            display dialog "There has been an error creating the file:" & return & return & m & return & "error number: " & n buttons {"Cancel"}
        end if
    end try
end Make_The_File

-- choose file
to get_the_file_name()
    set file_name to (choose file name with prompt ¬
        "Enter a name for the exported HTML file" default name ((thePlaylist's name as text) & ".html"))
    if file_name is false then error number -128 -- cancel
    --return file_name
end get_the_file_name

-- add TD stuff to eventual contents
to add_another_TD(x)
    if x is "" then set x to "<i>n/a</i>"
    my add_to_contents(TDopen & x & TDclose)
end add_another_TD

-- add text to eventual contents
to add_to_contents(x)
    if x is "" then set x to "&nbsp;"
    copy (html_contents & x & return) as string to html_contents
end add_to_contents

-- construct headers based on user selection
to make_headers()
    set do_number to 1
    set myNewHeaders to ""
    if myChoices starts with "Play Order" then
        set myNewHeaders to THopen & "#" & THclose
        --      copy items 2 thru -1 of myChoices to myChoices
        set do_number to 2
    end if
    set myNewHeaders to myNewHeaders & THopen & "Title" & THclose
    repeat with i from do_number to (count of myChoices)
        copy item i of myChoices to thisHeader
        set myNewHeaders to myNewHeaders & return & THopen & thisHeader & THclose
    end repeat

    return myNewHeaders
end make_headers

-- abbreviate date strings
to fix_date_string(x)
    set dateList to (my TextToList((x) as string, " "))
    set myDateAdded to ((((get characters 1 thru 3 of item 1 of dateList) as string) & ¬
        ", " & ¬
        (get characters 1 thru 3 of item 2 of dateList) as string) & ¬
        " " & (item 3 of dateList) & ¬
        " " & ¬
        (item 4 of dateList) & ¬
        " " & ¬
        (get characters 1 thru -4 of item 5 of dateList) as string) & ¬
        (item 6 of dateList) as string
    return myDateAdded as string
end fix_date_string

-- obligatory text->list,list->text GREAT SUBROUTUNES
on TextToList(theText, theDelimiter)
    set saveDelim to AppleScript's text item delimiters
    try
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {theDelimiter}
        set theList to every text item of theText
    on error errStr number errNum
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to saveDelim
        error errStr number errNum
    end try
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to saveDelim
    return (theList)
end TextToList

on ListToText(theList, theDelimiter)
    set saveDelim to AppleScript's text item delimiters
    try
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {theDelimiter}
        set theText to theList as text
    on error errStr number errNum
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to saveDelim
        error errStr number errNum
    end try
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to saveDelim
    return (theText)
end ListToText

to calc_total_time(totalSeconds)
    set theHour to totalSeconds div 3600
    if theHour is not 0 then
        set theHour to (theHour as string) & ":"
    else
        set theHour to ""
    end if
    set theMinutes to (totalSeconds mod 3600) div 60
    if theMinutes is not 0 then
        if theMinutes is less than 10 then set theMinutes to "0" & (theMinutes as string)
        set theMinutes to (theMinutes as string) & ":"
    else
        set theMinutes to "00:"
    end if
    set theSeconds to totalSeconds mod 60
    if theSeconds is less than 10 then set theSeconds to "0" & (theSeconds as string)
    -- gets the number of seconds after the minute
    return theHour & theMinutes & theSeconds as string
end calc_total_time

-- below is from SIZE OF FINDER SELECTION
-- ©1998 Sal Soghoian, Apple Computer
-- slightly modified for this script -- I have used a factor of 1024 and 1048576
-- but I am not completely happy with any results; they do not match what
-- is in iTunes' display exactly. However, there is less of a difference
-- created in this version of the script than in previous
to calc_size(x)
    if x > 1.0E+9 then
        set a to (x div 1.0E+9)
        set b to (x mod 1.0E+9) div 10000000 -- notice NOT 100000000
        set b to (round (b / 10) rounding up)
        if b > 9 then set b to 9
        set x to (a & "." & b as string) & " GB"
    else if x > 1048576 then
        set a to (x div 1048576)
        set b to (x mod 1048576) div 10000 -- notice NOT 100000
        set b to (round (b / 10) rounding up)
        if b > 9 then set b to 9
        set x to (a & "." & b as string) & " MB"
    else if x > 1024 then
        set a to (x div 1024)
        set b to (x mod 1024) div 10 -- notice NOT 100
        set b to (round (b / 10) rounding up)
        if b > 9 then set b to 9
        set x to (a & "." & b as string) & " KB"
    else
        set x to x & " Bytes"
    end if
    return x
end calc_size
```

source: http://dougscripts.com/067
Great Thanks to Doug Adams for all his work on these scripts

Answer (score 0):

there is a simpler way, that worked for me.

use applescript.

there is a siite called dougscript (http://dougscripts.com) there are a lot scripts and other helpers all around itunes.

i think the one which best fits your needs would be this one http://dougscripts.com/067

Comment: Unfortunately this seems to be an AppleScript compiled for PPC which will not run on current Mac models.

Comment: ok when i'm @home i would have a look at my mac and hopfully have the script there already converted to intel. i'll let u know if i have the script.

Comment: If have now look over it. My Script still works, butt i didn't use the One "Export to HTML" i use the "Export to HTML Table" One.

Comment: Can you fix the link in your answer then please?

Comment: if fix the link also if added a new answer with the script in it. hope this also works for you